# Issue with HTML5 Window Embed Statements in Safari 6

Tags: html, safari, html5-video, safari6

The issue is that video displayed in an HTML embed statement with percentage height and width used to scale to the window/frame that it belonged to. With a recent change to Safari (V6?), these videos are now being limited to a small, 1" x 1" box, regardless of the size of the screen. I am looking for more current HTML(5?) code to revert to the former behavior.

Thank you